# Array duplicate and formatting issue using map and split with React JS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, split, flickr

I am fetching the Flickr api for public photos and consuming a few different results.

When fetching the author it adds "nobody@flickr.com (" author ") in front of everything. I've managed to split out the first half 'nobody@flickr.com (" ' but having trouble with the other half. The idea is just to grab the author in between the the quotes:

nobody@flickr.com (" author ")

The other part is the photos shows up twice for some reason. Any thoughts?

```
let output = this.props.posts.map(e => e.author.split('nobody@flickr.com ("').map(f => <li><img src={e.media.m}/><h3>{f}</h3></li>));
```

**Answer if anyone needs it:**

```
const regex = /(?:"[^"]*"|^[^"]*$)/;
    let output = this.props.posts.map((e, index) => <li key={index}><img src={e.media.m}/><h3>{e.author.match(regex)[0].replace(/"/g, "")}</h3></li>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Regex to achieve that, which is a less fiddly than using `split`:

```js
const author = 'nobody@flickr.com (" author ")';
const name = 'nobody@flickr.com (" John Doe ")';
const regex = /\(" (.*?) "\)/;

console.log(
  author.match(regex)[1]
);

console.log(
  name.match(regex)[1]
);
```

So, for your code snippet:

```jsx
const regex = /\(" (.*?) "\)/;
let output = this.props.posts.map(e => <li><img src={e.media.m}/><h3>{e.author.match(regex)[1]}</h3></li>);
```

Comment: It's an error with the API request, not with this piece of code.

Comment: Seems like Axios is not supporting `jsonp`, so either find a workaround or use a different library.